# Get Date object from MySQL Database and show it on a formatted text field

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to get the date of birth from my database and display it on a JFormattedTextField. It should be displayed in mm/dd/yyyy format but it is stored as yyyy/dd/mm format. How would I go about it? Patient date of birth is stored as a java.sql.Date

```
    JLabel lbl3 = new JLabel("Date of Birth:");
    lbl3.setBounds(17, 129, 90, 22);
    lbl3.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    lbl3.setFont(new Font("Microsoft New Tai Lue", Font.PLAIN, 16));

    JFormattedTextField formattedDob = new JFormattedTextField();
    formattedDob.setEditable(false);
    formattedDob.setText("//");
    formattedDob.setBounds(201, 128, 183, 22);
    contentPane.add(formattedDob);  

JButton btnSearchPatient = new JButton("Search");
        btnSearchPatient.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                PatientSQL searchPatient = new PatientSQL();
                Patient staff = searchPatient.getBySSN(patient.getSsn());

            txtAddress1.setText(staff.getAddress1());
            txtAddress2.setText(staff.getAddress2());
            txtCity.setText(staff.getCity());
        }
    });
```

Here is my PatientSQL.java for reference (irrelevant code such as packages and functions were removed for easier reading):

```
public class PatientSQL {
    private SessionFactory factory;

    public PatientSQL() {
        try {
            factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);

            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    /* Method to CREATE a patient in the database */
    public void add(String fname, String lname, String ssn, java.sql.Date dob, String phoneNo, String address1, String address2, String city, String zipcode, String allergy1, String allergy2, String allergy3, String photo) {
        Patient patient = new Patient(fname, lname, ssn, dob, phoneNo, address1, address2, city, zipcode, allergy1, allergy2, allergy3, photo);

        add(patient);
    }

    public Patient getBySSN(String ssn) {
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Patient patient = null;

        try {
            patient = (Patient) session.get(Patient.class, ssn);

        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            System.err.println("Can not find patient ssn: " + ssn);
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

        return patient;
    }

}
```

Comment: crazy idea. Let mysql handle the storage of the date in its own format (`YYYMMDD`) and the you'll have a native type to output format as required.

Comment: If your date is stored as a Date then it has no format and you only need to apply formatting to it.

Comment: @danblack wish I could lol due to my region, I'm required to show it in another format by the professor

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to convert Date:
Use LocalDateTime#parse() (or ZonedDateTime#parse() if the string happens to contain a time zone part) to parse a String in a certain pattern into a LocalDateTime.
like:

```
String date_s = "2011/01/18"; 
SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/dd/mm"); 
Date date = dt.parse(date_s); 
SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
System.out.println(dt1.format(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly requirements call for silly answers:

```
CREATE TABLE patient (
...
dob_string VARCHAR(8),
dob_date DATE AS (STR_TO_DATE(dob_string,"%Y/%d/%m"))
)
```

So store into `dob_string`, and fetch from `dob_date` and then output format as required.

Answer (score 0):

If it is ok to use `SimpleDateFormat`

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
df.format(patient.getDob()); //I'm guessing what the get method is named but you get what I mean
```